# Angular Reactive Forms: Cannot find control with path

Tags: angular

I have read the angular docs and also previous question and solution for this question but still can't pinpoint what is wrong. As it is giving this error for only this two and not other formControl in the same property like for type,options,answer.
Only the first question, types has a dropdown to choose from. But for second question the dropdown is not there.

Angular form .ts code

```
 forms = this.fb.group({
    formId: [],
    title: ['Untitled Form'],
    description: ['Hello'],
    email: [''],
    questions: this.fb.array([]),
  });

this.questionsArr.forEach((item: Question, i) => {
      let tempQuestion = this.fb.group({
        type: [this.questionsArr[i].type],
        question: [this.questionsArr[i].question],
        answer: [this.questionsArr[i].answer],
        options: this.fb.array([...this.questionsArr[i].options]),
      });

      this.questions.push(tempQuestion);

  questionsArr: Question[] = [
    {
      type: '1',
      question: 'AngularJS is a ____',
      answer: 'Javascript Framework',
      options: [
        'Java Framework',
        'Javascript Framework',
        'HTML Framework',
        'SQL Framework',
      ],
    },
    {
      type: '1',
      question:
        'Among the following, on which architectural pattern is AngularJS based?',
      answer: 'MVVM architecture pattern',
      options: [
        'Decorator Pattern',
        'Observer Pattern',
        'MVVM architecture pattern',
        'MVC architecture pattern',
      ],
    }
]

types: string[] = ['Radio', 'Checkbox', 'Small textbox', 'Large textbox'];
```

Angular form html code(Only showing the questions part as the error is in this part)

```
<div formArrayName="questions">
      <ng-container
        *ngFor="let question of questions.controls; let i = index"
        formGroupName="i"
      >
        <div class="form">
          <div class="form__div">
            <input
              type="text"
              formControlName="question"
            />
            <label for="question" class="form__label form__label__title"
              >Question {{ i + 1 }}</label
            >
          </div>
          <select
                id="type"
                formControlName="type"
                class="form-control"
                (change)="onChange($event)"
              >
                <option [ngValue]="0" selected disabled>Select Type</option>
                <option
                  *ngFor="let typeTemp of types; let j = index"
                  [value]="j + 1"
                >
                  {{ typeTemp }}
                </option>
              </select>
          <app-option [sendToComponent]="question" formArrayName="options"></app-option>
        </div>
```

From the Option Component(Took the data and trying to display the data using another component)

```
 @Input('sendToComponent') quest: any | undefined;

 get options() {
    return <FormArray>this.quest.get('options');
  }
```

```
<div>
  <label>Options: </label>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let option of options.controls; let i = index">
    <input
      type="text"
      formControlName="i"
    />
  </ng-container>
</div>
```

Getting two errors both of same type

```
core.mjs:6402 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> i'
core.mjs:6402 ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'questions -> i -> question'
```

Q. Also had a question if I didn't add formArrayName during calling the Option component but in the Option Component html would it still work because it isn't giving an error .

Comment: see that is `[formGroupName]="i"`. When you use `[` `]` you equal to the value of the expresion (in this case "the value of `i`", else you equal to the "literal" -Angular look for a formGroupName "i"-. Idem if you has an FormArray of FormControls, is `[formControlName]="i"`-

Comment: Is there any difference between [formControlName]="I" and formControlName={{i}}. I have seen a lot of places where this is also used. But don't know why?

Comment: Both work but it would prefer the binding syntax (if the result of the interpolation is a string the result is basically the same). A good explain is in this [link](https://medium.com/ngconf/the-true-difference-between-and-bindings-in-angular-1b9a854ea1d6): "Property bindings are actually manipulating the DOM (**after** the HTML has been processed) and they get to preserve data types. Curly brace binding is string interpolation of the HTML (**simply replacing** the HTML string with the results of the binding) and always results in strings."

Answer (score 0):

> formGroupName="i"

Your template searches for a formGroup named `i`, not for the formGroup named by the content of `i`. Please change to

`[formGroupName]="i"`